# how can I animate this a bit better using jquery-ui's toggleClass?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-animate

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/zmhRK/

The problem is very graphical, so i don't think i can explain it any better than actually showing it in action on jsfiddle. The problem is that when you press [toggle] then you can see that the list item is expanding and in this transition effect all you see is the parents background color, this is rather ugly. SO, what i want is for the contents of the list item to be visible during the animation instead of visible only after the animation.

I know this is possible if i for example manage to set the style attribute to display:block on the element in transition, but then i would need some kind of a callback function to remove the display:block once the transition is complete. Afaik, this callback function doesn't exist.

Any idea's on how i can solve this?

Comment: Why don't you `slideDown()` instead of `toggleClass()`?

Comment: Because width changes in child elements are not eased in with slideDown. as observable by Jaspers solution

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.slideToggle()` to create your animation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidebar-menu-item-controls').append('[toggle]').click(function(){

        //select the parent of this element, then select the next sibling,
        //which is the UL associated with this click event
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(300);
    });
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/zmhRK/8/

Note that this also works for your nested ULs.

Comment: If you click toggle on the Channels list item, you can see the width snapping instead of easing. Any way of fixing this?

Comment: @netbrain If you set a width on the element that's too wide, and `overflow-x : hidden` on it's container, it should clip the content instead of changing the container's size. I tried adding a CSS Transition but couldn't get it to animate the width change...

Comment: Unfortunately clipping the content isn't an option.

Comment: @netbrain If you set a defined width for the container, you can add `word-wrap : break-word` and the inner contents will not overflow the container, but they will not hide either, words will break and re-flow to the next line: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: Setting a fixed width is not an option either i'm afraid. Very good suggestions btw, Keep em coming ;)

Comment: @netbrain I think I'm going to have to leave it up to you. Your HTML structure is quite complex, so it's hard to say what will work without lots of testing...

Comment: Well, i found one solution, but it's ugly ass hell.. http://jsfiddle.net/zmhRK/10/